# How to give the Parent access to the Childrens' state without lifting it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build a component that does trigger the rendering of its child components by a button. I have lifted the state up from the child to the parent , but in this case the state in each child is being changed with every change in any child.How can I prevent this (without Redux).Thanks !

Parent Component:

```
const Component1 = ({ ourList = example }) => {
  // state lift-up comming from 0
  const [product, setProduct] = React.useState('');
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = React.useState(0)
  const [price, setPrice] = React.useState(0)
  const [subtotal, setSubtotal] = React.useState(0)

  const [total, setTotal] = React.useState(0)

  const handleProduct = (event) => {
    setProduct(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleQuantity = (event) => {
    setQuantity(event.target.value)
  }


  const productList = Object.keys(ourList)

  const priceList = ourList[product]

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setPrice(priceList)
  }, [product, priceList])

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setSubtotal(price * quantity)
  }, [price, quantity])


  //until here form 0

  const [add, setAdd] = React.useState([])

  const handleAdd = () => {
    setAdd([...add,
      1])
  }

  const handleRemove = (id) => {
    const newAdd = add.filter((item) => item.id !== id)
    return setAdd(newAdd)
  }
  console.log(productList)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTotal(total + subtotal)
  }, [subtotal, total])

  return (
    <div>
      {add.length > 0 &&
        add.map(item =>
          <Component0 ourList={ourList} price={price}
            quantity={quantity} subtotal={subtotal} handleProduct={handleProduct}
            handleQuantity={handleQuantity} productList={productList} onRemove={() => handleRemove(item.id)} />
        )}
      <button onClick={handleAdd} >Add Another One</button>
      <p>Total:{total}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Child component:

```
const Component0 = ({ ourList, price, quantity, product, subtotal, handleProduct, handleQuantity, productList, onRemove }) => {


  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };


  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={handleOpen}>
        Open the select
        </Button>
      {productList.length > 0 &&
        <FormControl >
          <InputLabel id="demo-controlled-open-select-label">Product</InputLabel>
          <Select
            labelId="demo-controlled-open-select-label"
            id="demo-controlled-open-select"
            open={open}
            onClose={handleClose}
            onOpen={handleOpen}
            value={product}
            onChange={handleProduct}
          >
            {productList.map(item =>
              <MenuItem value={item}>{item}</MenuItem>
            )}
          </Select>
          <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Quantity" variant="outlined" value={quantity} onChange={handleQuantity} />
          <TextField disabled id="outlined-basic" label="Price" variant="outlined" value={price} />
          <TextField disabled id="outlined-basic" label="Subtotal" variant="outlined" value={subtotal} />
        </FormControl>}
      <button onClick={onRemove}>Delete</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You can provide an example using codesandbox ?

Comment: You need to give your mapped components a `key` so that React can track of what needs rerendering. see: [React#Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) `<Component0 key={item.id} ... >`

Comment: This is just the way React works. But it doesn't do a real rerender of each Child. Instead it builds a virtual DOM from your JSX-Code and compares this one with the DOM of the last rendering. Only the differences will be applied by React. If you really need some optimization you can read about `React.memo`: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo
But as long as you don't have any performance issues you shouldn't do premature optimization.